# href that only runs javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an a tag inside of a form that is used to remove uploaded files. I don't want the a tag to take the user to another section of the page, or try to submit the form or anything like that, I only want it to run a javascript function. How can I accomplish this? I'm not sure what to put in the href?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `#`:

```js
function doSomething() {
  alert('test');
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="doSomething(); return false;">Click me</a>
```

Really, any URL can go there - the `return false;` short-circuits the default behaviour of the link.

In general, if at all possible, it's best to use a real URL that does the same thing your JS does, for users who have JS disable. This is called "graceful degradation".

Answer (score 0):

You really need to add more code and examples to your questions in the future. Fortunately I know what you're actually asking.

In the function that runs when you click the link, you want to prevent its default behavior.

Here's a very simple example:

```
<a href="http://google.com" id="myanchor">
```

Javascript

```
document.querySelector('#myanchor').addEventListener('click', function (ev) {

  ev.preventDefault();

  // your code here.

});
```

Answer (score -4):

```
<form>
<!-- other inputs-->
<input type='button' onclick='run()' />
</form>
```

Then for the Javascript:

```
function run() {
    //do something
}
```